# How to reference dependencies packages into an Android Library like .aar file?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, google-play-services, android-library

I have an android-library plugin that uses several android libraries included as .jar files and referenced directly from my build.gradle file :

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
```

I would then issue a `gradlew assembleRelease` command to create a .aar file that would be usable within an android application. This has always been working well for me up to now.

I now need to use the Google Play Services in my android-library. As it is instructed in the official Android documentation (http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Setup), I need to include the Google Play Services as a library project by importing it from maven :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'
```

But when I build my .aar file, the Google Play Services do not seem to be included in it (my .aar file is only 200kb, and the Google Play Services .jar library is > than 1mb).

I've read that the Google Play Services should be referenced as an Android Library Module, but I can't manage to import it like that without compilation errors. Can someone help me to have the Google Play Services packaged into my android-library?

My android-library build.gradle file :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
    release {
        runProguard false
    }
}
```

My android application build.gradle file :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        defaultFlavor {
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'novom.anyware.anywaresdk:anywaresdk:0.1.0@aar'
}
```

When issuing a `gradle dependencies` from the root of my main module, here is my result :

```
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been depre
cated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
:MyOldApp:dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Project :MyOldApp
------------------------------------------------------------

_DefaultFlavorDebugApk
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+ -> 19.1.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0
\--- novom.anyware.anywaresdk:anywaresdk:0.1.0

_DefaultFlavorDebugCompile
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+ -> 19.1.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0
\--- novom.anyware.anywaresdk:anywaresdk:0.1.0

_DefaultFlavorReleaseApk
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+ -> 19.1.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0
\--- novom.anyware.anywaresdk:anywaresdk:0.1.0

_DefaultFlavorReleaseCompile
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+ -> 19.1.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0
\--- novom.anyware.anywaresdk:anywaresdk:0.1.0

_DefaultFlavorTestApk
No dependencies

_DefaultFlavorTestCompile
No dependencies

apk - Classpath packaged with the compiled main classes.
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+ -> 19.1.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0
\--- novom.anyware.anywaresdk:anywaresdk:0.1.0

archives - Configuration for archive artifacts.
No dependencies

compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+ -> 19.1.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0
\--- novom.anyware.anywaresdk:anywaresdk:0.1.0

debugApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled debug classes.
No dependencies

debugCompile - Classpath for compiling the debug sources.
No dependencies

default - Configuration for default artifacts.
No dependencies

defaultFlavorApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled defaultFlavor classes.
No dependencies

defaultFlavorCompile - Classpath for compiling the defaultFlavor sources.
No dependencies

instrumentTestApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled instrumentTest classes.

No dependencies

instrumentTestCompile - Classpath for compiling the instrumentTest sources.
No dependencies

instrumentTestDefaultFlavorApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled instrument
TestDefaultFlavor classes.
No dependencies

instrumentTestDefaultFlavorCompile - Classpath for compiling the instrumentTestD
efaultFlavor sources.
No dependencies

releaseApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled release classes.
No dependencies

releaseCompile - Classpath for compiling the release sources.
No dependencies

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 7.388 secs
```

Comment: Why do you think that you want "to have the Google Play Services packaged into [your] android-library"?

Comment: I want to use the Geofencing provided by the Google Play Services

Comment: That does not mean that Play Services should be packaged in the AAR. So, I will ask again: Why do you think that you want "to have the Google Play Services **packaged into** [your] android-library"?

Comment: Because when I use my android-library into an android application, when the method `GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable` is called, I get the following error : `E/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.` If there is a proper way of including those resources without having the Google Play Services packaged into my android-library, please show me how.

Comment: Run **`gradle dependencies`** on your application project (not the library project). If you have the `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'` directive in your AAR, and your application project depends upon the AAR, you should see the `play-services` dependency in the report. My guess is that you will not, perhaps because of some misconfiguration somewhere in your `build.gradle` files.

Comment: Since I am not yet an expert with gradle, I added my build.gradle files in my post, whilst I search for the misconfiguration

Comment: Hmmm... I don't use `flatDir`, but rather push my AARs to a Maven repo. Otherwise, your `build.gradle` files seem OK. I'd be interested to hear what **`gradle dependencies`** reports for the app.

Comment: Here is what I got when issuing a `gradle dependencies` command from the root of my project : 
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
:dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

No configurations

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 7.001 secs

Comment: Is the root of your project where your application is? Run **`gradle dependencies`** in the same place where you would run other Gradle commands for your app (e.g., **`gradle installDebug`**).

Comment: yeah I'm sorry for the mistake, I added this one in my post

Comment: OK, `flatDir` does not appear to be contributing to the dependencies report. Clearly, you're at least getting your AAR code into the build, though, otherwise you couldn't compile.

Comment: Yeah, it does not mention the dependencies of my aar file. And if it may give you another hint, even if I get an error log from the method `GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable`, it returns true, but hangs later when I instantiate the LocationClient object.

Comment: Did you fing a way to distribute your .aar with the required dependencies packaged in it?

Comment: No, I force the users of my library to use gradle, so the manifest merger includes the dependencies. If they are using a different version of one of my dependencies, I believe it won't work...

Comment: @CommonsWare is there a way to force users to compile certain libraries in their gradle dependencies if they use my library ?

Comment: @2cupsOfTech: Force? No. If you are distributing your library as an artifact in a repository, the metadata (e.g., POM file for a Maven repo) would indicate any libraries that you depend upon, and you can include version information in there. Developers using your library, in turn, can override your wishes. After all, it's their app, not yours.

Comment: @CommonsWare I was hoping to distribute my library as a direct downloadable .aar file without utilizing e.g. a Maven repo but I need to tell the user about its dependencies so trying to find the best way to do it ?

Comment: @2cupsOfTech: "so trying to find the best way to do it ?" -- write documentation. Have that on the Web site where you are distributing the library. Explain exactly what people have to do to use your library, including having dependencies.

Comment: @CommonsWare I should be able to publish a .aar closed source artifact through a Maven repo ?

Comment: @2cupsOfTech: Yes. If you have additional questions in this area, please start a new Stack Overflow question, rather than continuing to comment here.

Comment: @CommonsWare I did yesterday actually: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30202718/550393