# Warning about an Android Library project gradle dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am building an Android Library project using Android Studio. The type of the module is *'com.android.library'* in *gradle.build* file. This module has a number of dependencies:

```
dependencies {    
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
}
```

The module builds result in a .aar file. I want the user of the .aar file to be notified/warned about .aar dependencies so his project doesn't successfully builds till these dependencies are set inside his project. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the user of the .aar file to be notified/warned about .aar dependencies so his project doesn't successfully builds till these dependencies are set inside his project.

Well, to some extent, that would happen automatically, as their compile would fail.

If you distribute this AAR as an artifact in a repository, the repository metadata (e.g., POM file for a Maven repo) can contain information about these dependencies. Many build systems (Gradle, Maven, etc.) will use that to automatically download those dependencies as needed when the developer uses your artifact.

If you elect to distribute this AAR by other means (e.g., a QR code the size of a small mountain), you will need to tell developers that they need to include these dependencies through documentation of some sort.

Anticipating a follow-up question...

> I should be able to publish a .aar closed source artifact through a Maven repo ?

Sure. While Maven Central and JCenter are tailored for open source, you can certainly have your own repo. It's just a directory with certain contents. For example, I have my own repo for my open source libraries, and while my libraries are open source, there is nothing about the repo that would *require* the repositories to hold open source code.

Comment: can you point to a comprehensive tutorial/guide doing the above ?

Comment: @2cupsOfTech: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/locally-release-an-android-library-for-jcenter-or-maven-central-inclusion/ That blog post outlines publishing to a local Maven repo, which is just a directory on a locally-reachable filesystem. That may be all you need, if the consumers of the library are all local (e.g., a team with a shared fileserver). If you wish to publish this online, you can either use an official repo server (Sonatype, Bintray, etc.), or use a static host (I use Amazon S3).

Comment: @2cupsOfTech: The only limitation on the latter approach is that HTTP `GET` requests of a directory need to return the directory contents. That might be provided for you by your Web host. S3 does not, so I pre-generate that HTML using a `bash` script that I found lying around teh Interwebs somewhere. I then use the AWS command line tool (`aws`) to sync my local repo up to S3 (`aws s3 sync`) to publish the repository with the generated directory listings.

Comment: @2cupsOfTech: There are recipes for hosting a repo on GitHub, though I haven't tried it personally.

Comment: btw the compile doesn't fail, it only results in runtime exception. if compile would fail that would do my job